# Run Word VBA with msgbox via C# without user interaction

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I am running a macro in a Word document via C#, the macro basically creates a copy of the document and adds a couple of more attributes.

But the issue is that, my macro has a confirmation msgbox at some point of the code which needs user interaction.

I am using  the code below grabbed from MS's web site. So the question is;

**Is there any way to suppress or auto-confirm the messagebox shown on the run of macro?**

```
private void RunMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
{
    oApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        null, oApp, oRunArgs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is *your* macro, just change it so it does not show the confirmation msgbox.

When you need the macro in another context where the confirmation msgbox shall appear, add a boolean flag `useConfirmationMsgBox as Boolean` to your macro code, and show the MsgBox only when this flag is true. Then, provide two different entry points, one where useConfirmationMsgBox is set to true, and one where it is set to false.

Comment: thanks for the reply Doc Brown. I want to do this without editing macro code as it will affect lots of documents in our company... if I update the template, it will be really overhead:(...

Comment: If I got you right, you are not running one macro, but a dozens (or more?) of copies of the same macro? Your macro is not part of a document template which could be changed in a single place? Well, that will give you a maintenance nightmare fewer or later. In fact, it may be possible to send a simulated "Enter" key stroke using the Windows messaging system to the confirmation MsgBox, but these kinds of solutions tend to be very unstable, and I would not recommend that seriously. Better try to separate you macros from your documents.